# Generate 2 random integers simultaneously in Assembly

Tags: assembly, random, x86-16, tasm

### Backgroud

The function `rollCubes` rolls 2 cubes within each turn of a backgammon game.

### Issue

*When running:* `rollCubes` always returns `2-2, 4-4` or `6-6`.

#### [edit]

*When debugging (executing each line inside `turbo debugger`):* the function manages to produce two different random integers, but the cube `1` is never rolled.

It makes me wonder what prevents `rollCubes` from producing random integers when running the executable.

### Sourcecode

```
proc rollCubes
    xor cx, cx
    mov [hicube], 0 
    mov [locube], 0
    mov cx, 2
    addAgainHigh:
        ; Random number [0, 3] --> two rolls [0, 6]
        mov ax, 40h
        mov es, ax
        mov ax, es:6Ch ;Random number
        and al, 00000011b
        cmp al, 0 ;Make sure al isn't 0
        je addAgainHigh ;If 0, roll again
        add [hicube], al ;add to cube value
        loop addAgainHigh
    mov cx, 2
    addAgainLow:
    ; Random number [0, 3] --> two rolls [0, 6]
        mov ax, 40h
        mov es, ax
        mov ax, es:6Ch
        and al, 00000011b
        cmp al, 0
        je addAgainLow
        add [locube], al
        loop addAgainLow
    mov al, [locube]
    mov ah, [hicube]
    ret 
endp rollCubes
```

Comment: This is not a [mcve] - it's your whole program, not a cut down minimal example that still reproduces the problem.  Are you using the current time as a source of randomness?  That would explain getting the same result for 2 calls when no single-stepping.  See a PRNG once and use it.

Comment: I understand, though I had issues running the program not writing it so I thought it would be helpful to hand the code. Now that you mentioned the time I understand that the programs runs fast, so both cubes are the same. When I run each line of code the time changes. Would delaying a few milisecs help? Thank you

Comment: IDK how often `es:6Ch` updates.  Likely that would still be highly correlated, like either 2, 2 or 2, 3.  Just read the time once in your whole program to seed a PRNG.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator

Comment: [Ralf Brown says](https://github.com/cirosantilli/ralf-brown-interrupt-list/blob/master/inter61c/MEMORY.LST) it's updated every 55 ms, i.e. it's the 18 Hz timer.  A delay will certainly not be helpful; all it means is that the cubes will differ by the length of your delay (in timer ticks).  I second Peter's comment that you need to write an actual pseudorandom number generator.  A simple one isn't hard.

Comment: Thank you, tho I'm only in high-school, and we just started assembler a few months ago. This Wikipedia page seems like gibberish. Is there any easier explanation? What about using RNG_seed? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code reads some number (BIOS.Timer) and keeps only a subset of the possible values {1,2,3}. After repeating you have {2,3,4,5,6}. **You can never roll 1 this way**

A roll of a dice should produce a number from 1 to 6.

```
call myRandom    ; -> AX = [0,65535]
xor  dx, dx
mov  cx, 6
div  cx          ; -> Remainder DX = [0,5]
inc  dx          ; -> Dice is [1,6]
...

; IN () OUT (ax)
proc myRandom
    imul ax, [NextRandom], 25173
    add  ax, 13849
    xor  ax, 62832
    mov  [NextRandom], ax
    ret
endp myRandom
```

The code in this *myRandom* proc is a [pseudo random number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) that will produce 65536 unique 16-bit numbers before it will repeat itself. No sooner will it output the same number.

When I run the above code 80 times (*NextRandom* starts at 0), I get the following numbers for rolling the dice:

```
4,5,6,1,2,3,2,3,4,3, 2,3,6,5,6,3,4,3,4,1
6,5,6,5,4,3,6,1,2,5, 4,5,2,3,6,5,2,1,6,3
6,3,6,3,2,3,2,1,2,5, 2,1,2,3,4,1,6,5,4,1
4,5,4,5,4,1,2,1,2,3, 6,3,6,1,4,1,6,3,6,1
```

The distribution of these numbers is fine:

```
1 ~ 13
2 ~ 13
3 ~ 16
4 ~ 12
5 ~ 11
6 ~ 15
```

[**edit**]

> When running: rollCubes always returns 2-2, 4-4 or 6-6.
> It makes me wonder what prevents rollCubes from producing randoms when running the executable.

The BIOS.TimerTick at linear address 0040h:006Ch increments every 55 ms. This is a very long time in computers, and because your *rollCubes* procedure reads this counter **4 times in rapid succession**, you will nearly always receive the same value from it.

This is what happens most of the time:

- If TimerTick happens to end with **00**b

  ```
    addAgainHigh:
     00b  reread until it changes to 01b
     01b=1  hicube = 0 + 1 + 1 = 2
    addAgainLow:
     01b=1  locube = 0 + 1 + 1 = 2
  ```
- If TimerTick happens to end with **01**b

  ```
    addAgainHigh:
     01b=1  hicube = 0 + 1 + 1 = 2
    addAgainLow:
     01b=1  locube = 0 + 1 + 1 = 2
  ```
- If TimerTick happens to end with **10**b

  ```
    addAgainHigh:
     10b=2  hicube = 0 + 2 + 2 = 4
    addAgainLow:
     10b=2  locube = 0 + 2 + 2 = 4
  ```
- If TimerTick happens to end with **11**b

  ```
    addAgainHigh:
     11b=3  hicube = 0 + 3 + 3 = 6
    addAgainLow:
     11b=3  locube = 0 + 3 + 3 = 6
  ```

> When debugging (executing each line inside turbo debugger): **the function manages to produce random rolls** as should be.

Indeed, there's no longer the problem of **rapid succession**! Executing the program from within Turbo Debugger takes time. The BIOS.TimerTick at linear address 0040h:006Ch will (very probably) have incremented in between reads from your program.

> When debugging (executing each line inside turbo debugger): the function manages to produce **random rolls as should be**.

Not really! As stated in my earliest answer, you can never roll 1 this way.
Because your program throws out the zero, the following are all the sums your code can produce combining both sets {1,2,3} through addition:

```
1 + 1 = 2
1 + 2 = 3
1 + 3 = 4
2 + 1 = 3
2 + 2 = 4
2 + 3 = 5
3 + 1 = 4
3 + 2 = 5
3 + 3 = 6
```

Do notice that the numbers have very different probabilities this way.

Comment: Thanks for staying up to date with the post `:)` Finally I understand why my program throws the zero. In case I do use it, the comparison should be outside the scope of the rolling. I'll update ASAP!